# What is the solution of this definite integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I encountered this integral in my calculations:
[image]

Here, $n_0$ and $n_1$ are constants, such that $n_0$<$n_1$. Both constants are real and positive.

I tried to find solution in Table of integrals,series and products and by using Wolfram mathematica, but I have not managed to find it.

Comment: You can solve it with a Weierstrass substitution but the result is simply too long to been written here or to be useful to a human being IMHO

Comment: To evaluate it online analytically or numerically notice that applying the trigonometric identity $\sin^2(f) = \frac{1-\cos(2f)}{2}$ and the substitution $\cos(f)\mapsto t$ you can rewrite your integral as $\int_0^1 {\left({1 - \frac{2{n_1}^2 t}{n_0\sqrt{{n_0}^2t^2+{n_1}^2-{n_0}^2}+{n_1}^2t}}\right)^2dt}$